# pass parameters to function in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass data from a child component to the parent

```
const Main () => {
    const helloUser(name) => console.log("hello, name)
    return <User helloUser={() => helloUser } />
}

const User (props) => {
    const { helloUser } = props
    helloUser("john")
    return <p>User component</p>
}
```

it doesn´t work. it only works If i pass the data like this in the Main component

```
return <User helloUser={() => helloUser("john") } />
```

what I´m doing wrong? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrectly passing *() =>*

```
return <User helloUser={helloUser } />
```